# X230 CPU Clock Cycle Change When Battery Removed

Tags: windows-10, performance, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop, cpu-usage

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad x230 running Windows 10. It has a Samsung EVO SSD and works pretty good. However, it behaves strangely when the battery is out. As soon as I take the battery out, CPU clock cycle gets fixed to 1.20 GHZ and the computer slows down terribly, when battery plugged in, it is overclocked (2.99 GHZ over 2.60GHZ). All the BIOS settings are set to max performance.

Now I want the computer to be overclocked in both scenarios - battery out and in. Could someone tell me why taking the battery out changes CPU cycle? And how would I be able to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to my question. The right answer hadn't come up at the time of making the query.

https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/ThinkPad-X-Series-Laptops/ThinkPad-CPU-runs-at-reduced-maximum-clock-speed-with-no-battery/ta-p/545661

It says that when 65 W AC adapter is used, some models do this to prevent system shutdown. To use the CPU at full performance, either a more powerful adapter should be used or the battery should be attached.